# IOS Collection view cell first time click and removing selection when view appears

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using collection view, after collection view loaded if you click on any cell first time, click is not working.. If you click on another cell then the click is working.. It is happening when collection is loaded freshly.

I am using navigation controller and loading anther view using following code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoard", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ControllerID") as! UIViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

If we selected one cell and navigate to next view, when coming back to collection view, the previously selected element is not getting deselect.. So that click is not working on that cell. It is working if you click on another cell and come back and click on that.

Comment: is your question is : collection view cell is not selected on first time when user click on  collection view cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is problem with my code. I used `collectionView:didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` instead of `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

thank you all for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Once you load your data from data source, you should reloadData of `UICollectionView`, for the first problem, which you couldn't select any cell on first click.

for your second problem, while you came back from next view, item gets selected so you can not select again that item, the solution is that you can deselect item while you move from first screen to next view.

Like this,

```
[collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

I would happy if I can help you more if required.

Hope this help you.

Comment: thank you Viral. Issues is with my code. I used `didDeselect` instead of `didSelect` function.

Comment: Viral, I think your answer will help in other situation.. Just let us know where we need to reloadData of `UICollectionView` if we use Collection view in `ViewController`.